# How to return objects from asp.net core 3.0's UseRouting(...) delegate handlers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

With this new aspcore 3 routing technique of `app.UseRouting(...)` you can specify your own request delegates rather than map everything to controller actions.

However, these request delegates only have a `Task` return and no `Task<T>`. It seems you lose the ability to simply return a business object, which with a controller action would automatically be serialized into the response with an `IActionResult`.

If I have a route delegate such as:

```cs
options.MapGet("/getuser", async (httpContext) =>
{
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = httpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value
    };
});
```

How can I return that `user` in the response as serialized json or perhaps as a stream/pipe that the client can then work with?

Comment: You’ll have to write it yourself to the response stream when using this way using `httpContext.Response`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Sami Kuhmonen, I ended up writing to the response stream using `System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializer`

```cs
var user = new User
{
    UserName = httpContext.User.Claims.First(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name).Value
};

await JsonSerializer.WriteAsync(user, httpContext.Response.Body);
```